# Trying to make move list for game Tic Tac Toe

Tags: arrays, julia

I am trying to  make list  of game positions in tic tact toe.  When I use push! code in Julia the list that stores the game arrayslist changes the previous game position which makes the process useless.  I want a list like... [[position number one containing first move],[position number two move], etc... then the function at end should return the list.

Tried push! and append! not working theis Julia is not like Python!

```
# set up 3 by 3 array Want to get list of moves of X  after 
# they are chosen store in C 
C = []
A =[]
A = fill("",3,3)


# set up 3 by 3 array 

listpossmove= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in 1:3
    mov = rand(listpossmove)
    println(mov)
    A[mov] = "X"
    println()
    println(A)
    push!(C, A)
    println("C ",C)
    # this removes previous list of moves choice so that move is not placed
    #in previous square
    listpossmove = filter(x ->x!= mov, listpossmove)
    #println("final poss move",listpossmove
end
```

I expect out come to be

```
[["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "" "" ""],["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "X" "" ""],["X" "" ""; "" "X" ""; "X" "" ""]]
```

but get

```
["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "" "" ""]
Array{Any,1}
C Any[["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "" "" ""]]
3

["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "X" "" ""]
Array{Any,1}
C Any[["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "X" "" ""], ["X" "" ""; "" "" ""; "X" "" ""]]
5

["X" "" ""; "" "X" ""; "X" "" ""]
Array{Any,1}
C Any[["X" "" ""; "" "X" ""; "X" "" ""], ["X" "" ""; "" "X" ""; "X" "" ""], ["X" "" ""; "" "X" ""; "X" "" ""]]
```

Comment: Hei @Cliff, I tried to fix your formatting to make the code more readable. Please check whether I haven't changed any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

deepcopy() is your friend when saving arrays. The array you push needs to be a copy of the array you then modify.  try:

```
const C = []
const A = fill("",3,3)


# set up 3 by 3 array 

const listpossmove = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in 1:3
    mov = rand(listpossmove)
    println(mov)
    A[mov] = "X"
    println()
    println(A)
     push!(C, deepcopy(A))

    println("C ",C)
# this removes previous list of moves choice so that move is not placed
#in previous square
        filter!(x ->x!= mov, listpossmove)
        #println("final poss move",listpossmove


end
```